# Importing macros of a .csproj to a Directory.build.targets file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, msbuild

I have the following `Directory.build.targets` file located next to the solution file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <BinaryFormats Include="$(SolutionDir)Projects\BinaryFormats\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\BinaryFormats.dll" />
        <BinaryFormats Include="$(SolutionDir)Projects\BinaryFormats\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\BinaryFormats.pdb" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyUnityPlugins" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(BinaryFormats)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)Assets\Plugins" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Its job is to copy some class libraries to `$(SolutionDir)Assets\Plugins` and achieves in doing so.

One thing however, each of the file path to be copied is hard-coded.

**Question:**

Is it possible somehow to imports the macros of a .csproj and use them in the file?

For instance, to be able to use the following syntax instead of hard-coded paths:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BinaryFormats Include="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll"/>
    <BinaryFormats Include="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: With `$(SolutionDir)` you are already using a macro, so why shouldn't that work just out of the box? it is possible that some are not available, but I'm quite sure `$(TargetDir)` for instance is.

Comment: Are you saying that I should edit and put such file in Projects\BinaryFormats directory? Thing is, I'd like to apply Hollywood principle "Don't Call Us, We'll Call You.", i.e. not customize BinaryFormats for an external consumption.

Comment: Then I maybe missunderstood your question. Do you want to do the above for all projects in the solution? Does your actual .targets file contain many sections similar to the above?

Comment: @PMF This is really interesting, I've changed the content to be generic using `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName)...` and effectively, it works for multiple projects, each of their output is copied :)

Comment: That makes sense. The `.props` and `.targets` files are evaluated/executed for each project. Conditions (e.g `<PropertyGroup Condition="$(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('UnitTest'))">` will evaluate differently each time but can be put into these files.

Comment: Note Directory.build.props is evaluated quite early so some properties might not be available, but these 2 are. Additional note: it's not always the best idea to use it to modify builds in 'permanent' ways (as in: include the file in version control) because that makes it harder to customize the build in the way intended by it. Alternative is to just have another file and Import it in each project needing it.

Comment: @stjin makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. The `Directory.build.props` and `Directory.build.targets` files are evaluated respectively executed *for each project* separately. For each project, the corresponding macros (such as `$(TargetPath)` or `$(ProjectPath)`) will have the values for that particular project. So your above example `<BinaryFormats Include="$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb"/>` should just work as written.

With additional conditions, you can also use these files to conditionally extend your projects. For instance, I have a large solution (100+ projects) where the `Directory.build.props` contains this section:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="($(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('UnitTest')) OR $(MSBuildProjectName.EndsWith('IntegrationTest'))) AND '$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This automatically adds these two packages as references to all unit test projects (and only these), which not only reduces clutter on the project files themselves but also allows me to upgrade these packages with only changing a single line of code.